# finding two charts to cover the manifold $S^n$

Tags: manifolds, spheres, stereographic-projections

i have a problem in stereography of Manifold Sphere $S^n$ for finding two charts to cover it , still stereography is hard for me to understand but the problem is how can i find these 2 charts to cover $S^n$ and in how should i write the prove of locally euclidean property of this manifold (with math notation not explaining)

Comment: Do you know stereographic projection of $S^2$ already? This should be easy to visualise and be written down formally.

Comment: the problem is not stereographic of sphere , i want to know which 2charts are covers for $S^n$ .and where the stereographic gonna help? @edm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon\in\{-1,1\}$, $U_\varepsilon:=S^n\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0,\varepsilon)\}$ and $\varphi_\varepsilon\colon U_\varepsilon\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by:
$$\varphi_\varepsilon(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=\left(\frac{x_0}{1-\varepsilon x_n},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{1-\varepsilon x_n}\right),$$
then $\varphi_\varepsilon$is an homeomorphism which inverse is given by:
$${\varphi_\varepsilon}^{-1}(x)=\left(\frac{2x_1}{1+\|x\|^2},\ldots,\frac{2x_n}{1+\|x\|^2},\varepsilon\frac{\|x\|^2-1}{1+\|x\|^2}\right),$$
where $\|x\|^2={x_1}^2+\ldots+{x_n}^2$. Furtheremore, it is easily checked that $\varphi_1\circ\varphi_{-1}=\varphi_{-1}\circ\varphi_1$ is:
$$x\mapsto\frac{x}{\|x\|^2},$$
which is a smooth map. Whence, $\{(U_\varepsilon,\varphi_\varepsilon)\}_{\varepsilon\in\{-1,1\}}$ is a smooth atlas of $S^n$ formed by $2$ charts.

Does this little discussion answer your question? I am bit confused since you seem to already know about stereographic projections...

Comment: **pretty good** proof for my question.really thank you. i understand the whole proof .thank u again.from two weeks ago my teacher in university start teaching manifolds and i want to know is it OK that i can not solve problems like this by myself yet or not? @C.Falcon

Comment: Do not worry, manifolds are really abstract and elaborated objects, it is okay to have difficulties to wrap your head around them. In fact, Riemann was the first mathematician to give more or less a formal definition of a manifold. Regarding this precise question, I encourage you to try to understand how the formula for $\varphi_\varepsilon(x)$ is derived: draw a line from $(0,\ldots,0,\varepsilon)$ passing through $x$ and find its intersection with the hyperplane $\{x_n=0\}$.

Comment: thanks u make me hopeful.maybe its with posthaste but i thought about your question 20 minutes...the chart $\phi_\epsilon{U_x}=V{x}$ which V{x} is a ball with x center in a sphere $S^n$. the intersection between hyperlane and the line is x. am i right? @C. Falcon